# Assignment Guidance

Tags: vb.net

This is the third week of my intro to programming class and I'm stuck. I can get it to run I just can't enter more than 1 number. This is a vb console app.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim highestNumber As Integer = -1000000000
        Dim lowestNumber As Integer = 100000000
        Dim userInput As Integer

        Console.WriteLine("Input your numbers and when you are done enter -99.")
        Console.WriteLine("The app will then give the highest and lowest numbers entered.")
        userInput = Console.ReadLine()

        While userInput <> "-99"
            If userInput >= highestNumber Then
                highestNumber = userInput
            ElseIf userInput <= lowestNumber Then
                lowestNumber = userInput
            End If
        End While

        Console.WriteLine("The highest number you entered is: " & highestNumber)
        Console.WriteLine("The lowest number you entered is: " & lowestNumber)

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: There's a few things wrong. Are you looking for a review/cleanup? From what I can see a user can enter anything they want. `userInput` is an Integer not a string, you can't compare this that way. Turn Option Strict On. Also you can determine which one is the highest and lowest ...does it matter if you ask the user or not? Let say let them enter two numbers and show them the output.

Comment: The debugger will find mistakes like this *much faster* than you can compose an SO question.  Stepping thru the code like by line and watching variables change (or not) will help you think like the compiler and write better code.

Answer (score 0):

You're only executing `ReadLine` once, before the loop starts, so you only get to enter one number. As it currently stands, if you don't enter -99 then you have an infinite loop since you cannot change `userInput` inside the loop.

You need to put a copy of `userInput = Console.ReadLine()` at the end of the `While` loop so that a new value can be entered and the logic will be re-executed.

Also, you might as well remove the `=` signs from your tests. No point changing the highest/lowest unless the new number is actual higher/lower.

Comment: thank you I just figured that out right before I checked here. I'll remove the = signs. thanks again for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Move this line inside your while loop

```
userInput = Console.ReadLine()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. It checks the input of the user, if it's not an integer they can try again or enter -99 and get out... You can also change how many numbers a user enters by changing a few places where it shows `2`, or declare a variable and set it and then use it...

```
 Public Sub Main()

    Dim userInput As Integer = 0
    Dim lstInteger As New List(Of Integer)

    Console.WriteLine("Input your numbers and when you are done enter -99." & Environment.NewLine & "The app will then give the highest and lowest numbers entered.")

    Do Until userInput = -99
        If Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),userInput) AndAlso userInput <> -99 Then
            lstInteger.Add(userInput)
            If lstInteger.Count = 2 Then Exit Do
            userInput = 0
            If Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), userInput) AndAlso userInput <> -99 Then
                lstInteger.Add(userInput)
                If lstInteger.Count = 2 Then Exit Do
            Else
                If userInput = -99 Then Exit Do Else Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number.")
            End If
        Else
            If userInput <> - 99 AndAlso userInput = 0 Then 
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number.")
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If 
        End If
    Loop

    If lstInteger.Count = 2 Then 
       Console.WriteLine("The highest number you entered is: " & lstInteger.Max.ToString)
       Console.WriteLine("The lowest number you entered is: " & lstInteger.Min.ToString)
    End If 

    Console.ReadLine()          

End Sub
```